# How to get country list in system.xml

Tags: magento2, system.xml, magento2.2

I want to display list of country in my system.xml

```
<field id="country" translate="label" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Countries</label>
</field>
```

How we do this?

Answer (score 6):

Use class **`Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country`** for country list

```
<field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="16" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
</field>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<field id="country" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
<label>Select Country</label>
<source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model></field>
```